# Force a property to serialize into identity in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jsonidentityinfo

I have a class with

(disclaimer, I am writing in Kotlin, but I translate it into Java so more people can read it)

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    "id"
)
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    public int id;
    public List<Foo> fooList;
}
```

I want to serialize another object which contains a list of `Foo`s, but I want all entries in the serialized `fooList` to be IDs, not objects. One solution that came to mind was to sort them topologically in reverse order before serialization, as they form a directed acyclic graph. But that's obviously not a perfect solution, so I'm wondering if there's an annotation or an otherwise clean Jackson way to do something like that.

EDIT:
The class that contains a list of Foo looks like this:

```
public class Bar implements Serializable {
    public List<Foo> fooList;
}
```

And when I deserialize a `Bar` instance from this JSON:

```
{
  "fooList": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "fooList": [1]
    }, 
    {
      "id": 1,
      "fooList": []
    }
  ]
}
```

And then I serialize it back, I want the output to be the same as the input, but instead it's this:

```
{
  "fooList": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "fooList": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "fooList": []
        }
      ]
    },
    1
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you please add the code of the other class (in case it exists) that contains a list of Foo objects. And can you please add the json output data you are expecting given some input data.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear, sorry. On it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class that extends from `Foo` class to offer an alternative serialization for `fooList` using the annotation `@JsonGetter`, like a wrapper.

`Foo` class:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private List<Foo> fooList;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Foo> getFooList() {
        return fooList;
    }

    public void setFooList(List<Foo> fooList) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
    }
}
```

`Bar` class:

```
public class Bar implements Serializable {
    public List<FooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper> fooList;

    public List<FooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper> getFooList() {
        return fooList;
    }

    public void setFooList(List<FooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper> fooList) {
        this.fooList = fooList;
    }
}
```

`FooFooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper` is the `Foo` wrapper for serialization and it has a method to convert from `Lst<Foo>` to List<`FooFooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper`> that you will have to call at some point before serializing:

```
public class FooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper extends Foo {
    @JsonGetter("fooList")
    public List<Integer> serializeFooList() {
        return this.getFooList().stream().map(f -> f.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static List<FooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper> convertFromFoo(List<Foo> fooList) {
        return fooList.stream().map(f -> {
            FooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper fooSimplified = new FooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(f, fooSimplified);

            return fooSimplified;

        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

`Main` with some tests:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setId(1);

    Foo fooChild = new Foo();
    fooChild.setId(2);
    fooChild.setFooList(new ArrayList<>());

    Foo fooChild2 = new Foo();
    fooChild2.setId(3);
    fooChild2.setFooList(new ArrayList<>());

    foo.setFooList(Arrays.asList(fooChild, fooChild2));

    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.setFooList(FooJsonSimplifiedSerializationWrapper.convertFromFoo(Arrays.asList(foo)));

    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(foo));
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bar));
}
```

This code will print:

`Foo serialization: {"id":1,"fooList":[{"id":2,"fooList":[]},{"id":3,"fooList":[]}]}`

`Bar serialization: {"fooList":[{"id":1,"fooList":[2,3]}]}`

Another solution could involve using `Views` with `@JsonView` annotation and customizing the views to adapt the serialization to your needs but in my opinion is a more cumbersome solution.